# xbox 360 kinect beam angle issue with property change

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, kinect

trying to get the beam angle in a C# wpf and there is an exception being thrown on the If PropertyChange. Does anyone have an example of this project, I can supply more information if needed. I am trying to get the mics change the property but instead it is throwing an exception

```
        InitializeComponent();
        //Beam Angle Code
        this.DataContext = this.Rect;
        this.Loaded += delegate { ListenForBeamChanges(); };
    }

    private KinectAudioSource CreateAudioSource()
    {
        var source = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0].AudioSource;
        source.NoiseSuppression = true;
        source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = true;
        source.BeamAngleMode = BeamAngleMode.Adaptive;
        return source;
    }

    private KinectAudioSource audioSource;
    private void ListenForBeamChanges()
    {
        KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0].Start();
        audioSource = CreateAudioSource();
        audioSource.BeamAngleChanged += audioSource_BeamChanged;
        audioSource.Start();
    }

    public double _beamAngle;
    public double BeamAngle
    {
        get { return _beamAngle; }
        set
        {
            _beamAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BeamAngle");
        }
    }

    void audioSource_BeamChanged(object sender, BeamAngleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeamAngle = e.Angle * -1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what exception is being thrown?

Comment: it is stating that the property change is null

Answer (score 0):

see http://kinectaudioposition.codeplex.com

copying sample usage code from http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinect-Audio-Positioning

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler to care Window loaded
/// Construct KinectMicArray and draw contents
/// </summary>
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    kinectMic = new KinectMicArray();
    kinectMic.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(kinectMic_PropertyChanged);
    DrawContents();
}
/// <summary>
/// Event handler to care KinectMicArray property changed
/// Showing angles as number for debug
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void kinectMic_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    KinectMicArray ka = sender as KinectMicArray;
    this.myLabel.Content = string.Format("Beam = {0:F}; Source = {1:F};  ", ka.BeamAngleProperty, ka.SourceAngleProperty); 
}
```

Comment: that sample is based on older Kinect SDK (using Microsoft.Research.Kinect namespace), but I'm currently looking into forking it and fixing it to work with Kinect SDK 1.8 (for Kinect v1 and Kinect for Xbox 360 sensors). Other code you can checkout is the Kinect Explorer WPF sample from the Kinect SDK, see the KinectManager.cs and the AudioVisualizer.cs

Comment: I have ported that KinectAudioPositioning sample to Kinect SDK v1.8 - Please see my post at https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/howto-upgrade-kinect-audio-positioning-code-from-older-beta-sdk/ for more info on what changes were needed to port from the older Microsoft Research Kinect Beta SDK. I have uploaded my version to http://kinectaudioposition.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches